# What's the best way to download a ZIP file with a large amount of dynamically generated PDFs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, prawn

In my Rails app a `user` can create up to 3000 `invoices` per month. For each invoice s/he can generate an invoice PDF as well. This happens on the fly, i.e. the PDFs never get saved anywhere on the server.

I'd like my users to have the ability to download **all** their invoice PDFs as a single ZIP file.

I am using [Prawn PDF](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn) and the [ZIP tricks gem](https://github.com/WeTransfer/zip_tricks) in my current solution:

```
class InvoicesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    invoices = current_user.invoices
    respond_to do |format|
      format.zip do
        DownloadInvoiceArchive.call(invoices, response, view_context)
      end
    end
  end

end
```

---

```
class DownloadInvoiceArchive

  include ActionController::Live

  LIMIT = 100

  def self.call(invoices, response, view_context)
    zipname = "invoices.zip"
    disposition = "attachment; filename=\"#{zipname}\""

    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = disposition
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/zip"
    response.headers["Last-Modified"] = Time.now.httpdate.to_s
    response.headers["X-Accel-Buffering"] = "no"

    writer = ZipTricks::BlockWrite.new do |chunk|
      response.stream.write(chunk)
    end
    ZipTricks::Streamer.open(writer) do |zip|
      invoices.each_with_index do |invoice, index|
        break if index == LIMIT
        file_name = "#{invoice.number}.pdf"
        zip.write_deflated_file(file_name) do |file_writer|
          pdf = InvoicePdf.new(invoice, view_context)
          file_writer << pdf.render
        end
      end
    end
    response.stream.close
  end

end
```

The performance of this approach is quite bad, though, because it takes forever to iterate through thousands of invoices and generate a PDF for each one. (Generating one PDF creates at least 5 SQL queries alone.)

So my question would be how the performance can be improved here.

One option might be to run the PDF generation in a background job and then email a download link to the user when it's ready. But where should the ZIP file then be stored? In the file system of the server or on Amazon S3? The data is highly confidential and must be deleted after the download.

So what would be the best approach here? Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: you can find some info about zip download here https://www.rubyonrails.ba/single/streaming-large-zip-files-in-rails

Comment: You definitely need to delegate this out to a series of background jobs to free your web threads - generating reports and packing them can be separate jobs. You're going to need tons of worker processes if there is any kind of load. I would really look into optimizing the PDF generation as much as possible as thats going to be the major bottleneck. I would look into SQL views which could help you reduce the number of queries.

Comment: And you don't want to use `ActionController::Live` here. It will tie up the web thread until the whole process is done. Instead use ActionCable (websockets) to notify the client of the progress and when the download is ready. Using Amazon S3 is a pretty good idea since its way better then Rails at serving files fast.

Comment: Sending a (S3) download link is equivalent to sending the files per email. Don't do that if the content is confidential. Just send a notification that the zip archive is ready, let the user log in to your application and present the download link there, in a secured environment.

Answer (score 2):

If it's too long to be handled in a HTTP request you must move it to a background job. You can make it *way* quicker tho by saving generated invoices on the server, which BTW sounds like a good idea anyways since in many countries invoices have to be stored in an "unchangeable" data format.

If you DB is on the same server as your invoices would be it probably won't cause any major security concerns.

Is there any particular reason why you're not saving them atm?

Comment: Hi Kamil, thanks for your advice. I never saw the need to save the PDFs thus far. Plus, storing so many PDFs sounds cumbersome and insecure to me. They would also have to be kept in sync with the *actual* data in the database at all times which I find difficult to implement.

Comment: @Tintin81 what do you mean by _"kept in sync"_ – can invoices change after being created?

Comment: @Stefan: Yes, they can be updated or destroyed. The PDFs need to reflect those changes at all times which I find tricky and cumbersome to implement. It's also prone to errors. Or is it not? That's why I prefer generating the PDFs on the fly rather than storing them somewhere. But I am open for suggestions here.

Comment: @Tintin81 you might want to check the legal requirements for invoicing. Usually you're not allowed to simply change an invoice retroactively, or to discard it.

Comment: @Stefan: The legal requirements say that you're not allowed to edit an invoice **after** you sent it. But before sending it, you're allowed to make as many changes as you like.